# Not able to use terraform command on OpenFaas Python 3 Function deployment

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kubernetes, terraform, openfaas

I am using a Openfaas Python3 function with terraform to create bucket in my AWS Account. I am trying it locally and created a local cluster using k3s and installed openfaas cli.
Steps:
Created local cluster and deployed faas-netes.
Created a new project using openfaas template of python3.
Exposed the port.
Changed my project yaml file with new host on gateway key in provider.
I am creating my tf files with python only and I am sure that the files are created with proper info as checked it by executing ls and printing the file data after closing the file.
Checked if terraform is installed in image and live by executing terraform--version.

I have already changes my dockerfile to have terraform installed while building image.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 Docker: 20.10.15 Faas-CLI: 0.14.2

Docker File

```
FROM --platform=${TARGETPLATFORM:-linux/amd64} ghcr.io/openfaas/classic-watchdog:0.2.0 as watchdog
FROM --platform=${TARGETPLATFORM:-linux/amd64} python:3-alpine

ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG BUILDPLATFORM

# Allows you to add additional packages via build-arg
ARG ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE

COPY --from=watchdog /fwatchdog /usr/bin/fwatchdog
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/fwatchdog
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE}
RUN apk add --no-cache wget
RUN apk add --no-cache unzip

RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.1.9/terraform_1.1.9_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_1.1.9_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/bin/
RUN rm terraform_1.1.9_linux_amd64.zip


# Add non root user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser app -S -G app

WORKDIR /home/app/

COPY index.py           .
COPY requirements.txt   .

RUN chown -R app /home/app && \
  mkdir -p /home/app/python && chown -R app /home/app
USER app
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/app/.local/bin:/home/app/python/bin/
ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/app/python

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target=/home/app/python

RUN mkdir -p function
RUN touch ./function/__init__.py

WORKDIR /home/app/function/
COPY function/requirements.txt  .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target=/home/app/python

WORKDIR /home/app/

USER root

COPY function           function

# Allow any user-id for OpenShift users.
RUN chown -R app:app ./ && \
  chmod -R 777 /home/app/python

USER app

ENV fprocess="python3 index.py"
EXPOSE 8080

HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s CMD [ -e /tmp/.lock ] || exit 1

CMD ["fwatchdog"]
```

Handler.py

```
import os
import subprocess

def handle(req):
    """handle a request to the function
    Args:
        req (str): request body
    """
    print(os.system("terraform --version"))
    with open('terraform-local/bucket.tf','w') as resourcefile:
        resourcefile.write('resource "aws_s3_bucket" "ABHINAV" { bucket = "new"}')
        resourcefile.close()
    with open('terraform-local/main.tf','w') as mainfile:
        mainfile.write('provider "aws" {' + '\n')
        mainfile.write('access_key = ""' + '\n')
        mainfile.write('secret_key = ""' + '\n')
        mainfile.write('region = "ap-south-1"'+ '\n')
        mainfile.write('}')
        mainfile.close()
    print(os.system("ls"))
    os.system("terraform init")
    os.system("terraform plan")
    os.system("terraform apply -auto-approve")
    return req
```

But still not able to use terraform commands like terraform init and create bucket on AWS.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question here?

Comment: Not able to use terraform commands.

Comment: Is there an error? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: It is not showing any error while building, pushing, or deploying. But the commands don't work simply as the providers will be downloading when the first command terraform init is executed. But i am sure that terraform is installed on my docker image as the command terraform --version returns a valid response with version of terraform to be 1.1.9. Will attach a screenshot for same.

Comment: Ah, ok. And why run terraform commands with Python? Why not just run plain `terraform init/plan/apply`?

Comment: I am trying to use these commands on openfaas deployment. Can you explain the plain part I have tries to hit commands using os and subprocess but no use.

Comment: if I am commenting the init part then

Comment: Internal Server Error
Can't reach service for: terraform-test.openfaas-fn. This error is shown on deployment

Comment: If I am not commenting the init part then the code is executed with this error : [31m│ [0m [0mTo make the initial dependency selections that will initialize the
[31m│ [0m [0mdependency lock file, run:
[31m│ [0m [0m  terraform init

Comment: I'm saying that if you only need to run terraform commands in the container, there is no need to use Python for that, just create a step in which you would run the terraform commands.

Comment: No was trying to do it in python so that I don't need to create resource manually just need to send my bucket name and will be created.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.